# How can you visualize data frames in a good way?

Tags: r

Given that you have a data frame with a lot of columns and rows, how can you visualize this in a good way?

I have imported my data from excel, where I in a clear way can browse my data. However, when I import it as a data frame into R, things get more complicated. I quickly get lost in the output in my terminal window. Could I output my data frame into some form of more easily accessible form for viewing, something that looks more the way it would look in excel?

Comment: What is it that you are looking for?  In general, you're better off letting the software find things for you.  E.g.,  `foo <- my_big_dataframe[my_big_dataframe$x >1] ` will find outliers far more reliably than scanning a printout by eye.   And beyond that, there's a reason graphs are sometimes referred to as "visual representations of data" :-)

Comment: There's a cool viewer documented at http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Talks/viewer.pdf but I don't think it ever got very far beyond proof-of-concept ...

Comment: @CarlWitthoft well, often I just want to browse the data and get a feel for what I'm actually looking at. There are several occasions when I just want to look at it without searching for anything specific just to see if everything seems to hold up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RStudio](http://rstudio.org/) does a pretty good job with its built-in (read-only) data viewer. Other solutions have been suggested on Cross Validated: [Is there a good browser/viewer to see an R dataset (.rda file)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11551/930).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I love RStudio :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `edit(my.data.frame)`.

It will open your data.frame into the default editor specified by `getOption("editor")`. You can use `option(editor = ".......")` to change that default, or just use the `editor=` option when calling `edit`. This is only relevant for Unix users.

Finally, I'll bring your attention to this important portion of the `?edit` documentation:

> It is important to realize that `edit` does not change the object called name. Instead, a copy of `name` is made and it is that copy which is changed. Should you want the changes to apply to the object `name` you must assign the result of `edit` to `name`. (Try `fix` if you want to make permanent changes to an object.)

Comment: For me `edit` open a window with a very basic viewer, not the  program in `options(editor)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/), an R interface to the [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) library.

Here is a quick function to visualize a dataframe in your browser:

```
viewdf <- function(df,
                   to_truncate = NULL,
                   truncate_max = 10,
                   truncate_max_title = 200,
                   types_in_colnames = TRUE,
                   filter = "top",
                   to_round = NULL,
                   to_round_digits = 2) {
  # column names to display
  newcolnames <- colnames(df)
  for (i in seq(1, length(newcolnames))) {
    newcolnames[i] <- stringr::str_replace_all(newcolnames[i], "_", " ")
  }
  if (types_in_colnames) {
    for (i in seq(1, length(colnames(df)))) {
      col <- colnames(df)[i]
      newcolnames[i] <- paste0(
        newcolnames[i],
        "\n{",
        class(df[[col]]),
        "}"
      )
    }
  }
  # We need to replace NA values with a character value
  # for columns we are going to truncate,
  # otherwise DT crashes and show an empty table
  to_truncate_ix <- which(colnames(df) %in% to_truncate)
  l <- list()
  for (el in to_truncate) {
    l[[el]] <- "NA"
  }
  df %<>% tidyr::replace_na(l)
  # Generate DT table
  dtobj <- DT::datatable(df,
    colnames = newcolnames,
    filter = filter,
    options = list(
      pageLength = 20,
      filter = "top",
      autoWidth = TRUE,
      columnDefs = list(list(
        targets = to_truncate_ix,
        render = DT::JS(
          "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
          "return type === 'display' && ",
          "data.length > ", truncate_max, " ?",
          "'<span title=\"' + ",
          "data.substr(0,", truncate_max_title, ") + ",
          "'...\">' + ",
          "data.substr(0, ", truncate_max, ") + ",
          "'...</span>' : data;",
          "}"
        )
      ))
    )
  )
  # Round number columns
  for (col in to_round) {
    dtobj %<>% DT::formatRound(col, to_round_digits)
  }
  return(dtobj)
}
```